# Git Bash for both Ubuntu/Linux and Windows requires ssh-agent on restart

Tags: shell-script, windows, git

Each time I need to use git for both my Linux server as well as my home computer running Windows 10, I need to start ssh-agent, then provide it with my GitHub RSA key, the problem being that doing so requires root privileges (i.e. entering the root password with each instance of needing to run `ssh-add <keyname>`). So within this I have three questions.

1. My first question is, why is this needed for Git, but not for SSH connections or SSH copy programs?
2. How do I make a single bash script that automatically starts the `ssh-agent` and adds all of my keys via `ssh-add`, even though those operations require passwords.
3. How do I use the aforementioned script on the GitHub bash command line programs for Windows?

Comment: `ssh-agent` doesn't require root privileges.It may be started from the shell initialization scripts of any user.

Comment: I've edited the post to contain the correct information.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to write a script with this commands using piping like:

```
echo 'yourpassword' | ssh-add
```

but it's not safe enough and not recommended.

You can use git tools to remember passwords both on Linux and Windows